# SSIS left merge join partial matches

Tags: ssis, merge, left-join, string-matching

In SSIS, when I'm trying to do merge join for table 1 and table 2 on "CourseName", the result shows only part of the column is mapped. That is , even though the values in those two tables are in the same datatype and have same "Coursename" , they are considered as "not match" in Left Merge Join in SSIS. Could someone help me out?

P.S.

1. The data type for both columns are nvarchar(30)
2. Lookup is also not working...

Comment: Could you provide a screenshot of the Merge Join component?

Comment: Thx so much for your quick response! Sorry but I could not provide it because of privacy issue.... Finally I figured out the reason, which is the different case in those two columns. :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A few things to consider:

1. Do you perform the sort at data source level? I have had problems with sort results at data source level being different than when I would perform a sort in SSIS, probably due to a different encoding being used.
2. Have you trimmed your column? Also have a look at case sensitivity.

Comment: Thx! Yes, the reason is case sensitivity so I use "Upper" for both columns and it's working!

Comment: My issue was due to the sorting.  I removed sorting from the sources and added separate sorting tasks, then did the merge join.  Everything worked after that.  P.S. This was especially the case when the two source DBMS engines were different, e.g., DB2 and SQL Server.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue, my problem is solved with Trimming column data.